# Points question xsim package precision decimal

Tags: latex3, xsim

How can I customize the score accurately as a 1.0 is not able to recognize.

Look in MWE

I like show points **1.0 and 2.0**, if points is major 1.001 show in points questions, how change this

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage[no-files]{xsim}

\newcommand*\circled[2]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
        \node[shape=circle,fill,inner sep=2pt, text=white] (char) {#1};}}
%%%%%-Custom Xsim exercises %%%%%
\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{custom}
{%\item[\GetExerciseProperty{counter}]
    \Needspace*{0\baselineskip}
    \noindent
    \circled{\XSIMmixedcase{\GetExerciseProperty{counter}}}~~~%
    \noindent
    \IfInsideSolutionF{%
        \GetExercisePropertyT{points}{ % notice the space
            (%
            \printgoal{\PropertyValue}
            \IfExerciseGoalSingularTF{points}
            {%\XSIMtranslate{point}
            }
            %{\XSIMtranslate{points}}%
            )%
        }
}}
{\vspace{\baselineskip}}


\xsimsetup{
    collect = false,
    exercise/within = section,
    exercise/template = custom,
    exercise/the-counter =  \arabic{exercise},
}



\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}[points=1.0]
Example 1
\end{exercise}


\begin{exercise}[points=1.001]
Example 1
\end{exercise}



\begin{exercise}[points=2.0]
    Example 2
\end{exercise}




\begin{exercise}[points=1.5]
    Example 3
\end{exercise}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage[no-files]{xsim}

\xsimsetup{
  goal-print={\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed zerofill,precision=1]{#1}}
}

\newcommand*\circled[2]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
        \node[shape=circle,fill,inner sep=2pt, text=white] (char) {#1};}}
%%%%%-Custom Xsim exercises %%%%%
\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{custom}
{%\item[\GetExerciseProperty{counter}]
    \Needspace*{0\baselineskip}
    \noindent
    \circled{\XSIMmixedcase{\GetExerciseProperty{counter}}}~~~%
    \noindent
    \IfInsideSolutionF{%
        \GetExercisePropertyT{points}{ % notice the space
            (%
            \printgoal{\PropertyValue}
            \IfExerciseGoalSingularTF{points}
              {\XSIMtranslate{point}
              }
              {\XSIMtranslate{points}
              }%
            )%
        }
}}
{\vspace{\baselineskip}}


\xsimsetup{
    collect = false,
    exercise/within = section,
    exercise/template = custom,
    exercise/the-counter =  \arabic{exercise},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{exercise}[points=1.0]
    Example 1
\end{exercise}

%\begin{exercise}[points=1.001]
%    Example 1
%\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}[points=2.0]
    Example 2
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}[points=1.5]
    Example 3
\end{exercise}
\end{document}
```